# Error in SQLite query on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

My code:

```
Cursor mCursor = mDB.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] {NUMBER, INVOICEID, SNAME, NUMBERPHONE, ADDRESS, URL, STATUS, IDDELIVER }, IDDELIVER + "='" + iddeliver+"'" + "AND"+ STATUS+"='Chuagiao'", null, null, null, null, null);
```

I don't false at postion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use this:

```
Cursor mCursor = mDB.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] {NUMBER, INVOICEID, SNAME, NUMBERPHONE, ADDRESS, URL, STATUS, IDDELIVER }, IDDELIVER + "='" + iddeliver+"'" + " AND "+ STATUS+"='Chuagiao'", null, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot the spaces in the `"AND"`

Your query should be like this : `"iddeliver AND STATUS='Chuagio'`

And currently it looks like this : `"iddeliverANDSTATUS='Chuagio'`